# How to transfer values into reproducible code

Tags: r

I know how to manually create reproducible code, e.g.

```
a<-c(0,1,1,0,0,1)
b<-c("A","B","A","B","A","B")
c<-c(1,1,2,2,3,3)
```

However, I want to provide the code with my actual data (with >100 rows) is there a way to "copy" the dataframe into a code format without typing the individual values? (i.e. a<-c(0,1,... for all my values))

Thank you very much!

Comment: did you try dput()?

Comment: see [How to Make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example?rq=1) Short version: use `dput(my_data)`

Comment: Great! That does the trick. I'll read the suggested page! \